# C# TabPage ImageIndex change

Tags: c#, tabpage

So, I'm working with code from someone else and I keep seeing this sort of thing:

```
if (page.ImageIndex != 2)
{ 
    page.ImageIndex = 2; 
}
```

Now, from a logical standpoint, this doesn't seem to make sense, so I'm wondering if there's some sort of event that fires when you change the image that they don't want to set off (I have searched for one but I didn't see one - I saw `BackgroundImageChanged`, but that seems to be something else), or if maybe setting an `ImageIndex` value, even if it's the same, causes a flash or flicker, or something?

Just wondering what I'm missing.

Thanks all!

Comment: I know for TreeView for example assigning to any ImageIndex causes the whole tree view to create a new window handle, and also to collapse all nodes except the one containing the node in question. There is probably the same thing going on here, and checking the source code for TabPage ImageIndex setter confirms this, because it causes a redraw of the whole tab control: https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.windows.forms/winforms/managed/system/winforms/TabControl.cs,7f9365c3d438160b

Comment: Thanks for the resource!  This looks like it might be tremendously useful.I may go with this as the answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the ImageIndex for Windows Forms controls sometimes has unexpected side effects.

You can see a similar problem in this post where the OP experiences unexpected collapse of nodes with their tree view

[Strange auto-collapse behaviour in a treeview when SelectedImageIndex is set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60906532/strange-auto-collapse-behaviour-in-a-treeview-when-selectedimageindex-is-set/60907849#60907849)

So for TreeView for example, changing the SelectedImageIndex causes the whole tree view to create a new window handle, re-draw, and also to collapse all nodes except the one containing the node in question.

There is probably the same thing going on here, and checking the source code for TabPage ImageIndex setter confirms this, because it causes a redraw of the whole tab control:

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.windows.forms/winforms/managed/system/winforms/TabPage.cs,cec4a25e4fa0d595

```
set_ImageIndex() => UpdateParent() => parent.UpdateTab() => TabControl.UpdateTabSelection()
```

https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.windows.forms/winforms/managed/system/winforms/TabControl.cs,1b31148fc95aa30d

because, of course, the framework has to cover everything:

```
// After changing the Bounds of TabPages, we need to
// make TabPages Redraw.
// Use Invalidate directly here has no performance
// issue, since ReSize is calling low frequence.
tabPages[index].Invalidate();
```